# Why does NetworkManager-dispatcher fail from Puppet but works fine from command line?

Tags: puppet, rhel7

I am writing a puppet manifest for use on RHEL7 system where I have this Service resource.

```
service {'NetworkManager-dispatcher':
   enable  => true,
   ensure  => running,
}
```

Puppet version:

```
# puppet -V
4.5.2
```

But after I run 'puppet agent -t' and check on the NetworkManager-dispatcher I find that it is dead.

```
● NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-dispatcher.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Feb 13 18:02:07 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb 13 18:02:07 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Feb 13 18:07:01 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb 13 18:07:01 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Feb 13 18:13:31 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb 13 18:13:31 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Feb 13 18:15:49 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb 13 18:15:49 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Feb 13 18:19:35 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb 13 18:19:35 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
```

When I execute from the command line everything seems fine:

```
# systemctl -l restart NetworkManager-dispatcher
# systemctl -l status NetworkManager-dispatcher
● NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-dispatcher.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-02-13 18:28:58 GMT; 1s ago
 Main PID: 28944 (nm-dispatcher)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
           └─28944 /usr/libexec/nm-dispatcher

Feb 13 18:28:58 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb 13 18:28:58 mgmt-01 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
```

Comment: Can you include the Puppet agent/apply logs, preferably with --debug showing that the service is started?

Comment: I was going to make the same request as @DominicCleal, but also would like to see the `journalctl` for network-manager while Puppet is making its changes to the service.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL7 uses systemd for managing services.
You missed to mention your puppet version.

Maybe you need to add

```
provider => 'systemd'
```

attribute to your service resource.

Comment: Thanks I add my puppet version to the question and will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: That didn't hurt but it didn't fix the issue with the NetworkManager-dispatcher being dead after the "puppet agent -t" execution.